# How to hide and unhide an image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)press:(id)sender {
    UIImage *bomb = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bom"];
    UIImageView *bom =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bomb];
    [bom setFrame: CGRectMake(83,115,35,35)];
    [self.view addSubview:bom];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [bom setFrame:CGRectMake(149,47,35,35)];



    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [bom setFrame:CGRectMake(134,40,60,55)];
         [bom setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash"]];



         hits++;
         _hit.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",hits];
     }];

}
```

Here is my code! The object bom here handles the imageview for splash.png image and i want that image to be appeared only for 0.5 sec when each time the button is pressed

Comment: Inside the animationWithDuration you should put bom.alpha = 1.0 or 0.0 depending on what you want

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an NSTimer that calls a method which hides the image.  You would have to keep a reference to the bomb.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)hideImage {
    self.bomb.hidden = YES;
}
```